# No close/close-recommendation button for me

Tags: support

I need to understand some moderation rules applicable to me. Currently, when for other peoples post, i don't see any close button. All i can do is either downvote or flag the post. If i feel that question doesn't belong to this site, Should i flag it or downvote to recommend closing the question ?

Answer (score 5):

From the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation)

> 250   Vote to close, reopen, or migrate **your** questions
>   300   Create new tags
>   500     Retag questions
>   1000    Show total up and down vote counts
>   2000    Edit other people’s posts, vote to approve or reject suggested edits
>   3000    Vote to close, reopen, or migrate **any** questions

I hate to say it, but *seriously* - read the whole FAQ. :) Clicking on each header expands it so you see the whole section (and doing all of them, gets you a *badge*).

And yes, if you think a Question *should* be closed - flag it.

Comment: thanks mate. I read it when i joined but Will do that again. And also will flag questions that i think should be closed. I was worried if flag can only be used for profanity or other question which disrespects or create flame-war.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not a section on *flagging* in the FAQ :( But you can click the *flag* button and see what kinds of reasons are available. In *particular*, click on the `doesn't belong here` option, and see what choices are there. You **can** cancel before posting the flag, so don't worry about accidently posting. :)